# How to count the number of times two values appear in two columns in any order

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

Lets say, we have this table :

```
+------+------+
| COL1 | COL2 |
+------+------+
|   A  |   B  |
+------+------+
|   B  |   A  |
+------+------+
|   C  |   D  |
+------+------+
```

I want to count the number of times either `letter1, letter2` or `letter2, letter1` appears in the two columns.

I want the result :

```
+------+------+------+
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
+------+------+------+
|   A  |   B  |   2  | 
+------+------+------+
|   C  |   D  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
```

**NOTE:** It can be either `AB` or `BA` doesn't matter.

I tried:

```
SELECT
COL1,COL1,COUNT(*) AS COL3
FROM
X
GROUP BY COL1,COL2;
```

But that gets me :

```
+------+------+------+
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
+------+------+------+
|   A  |   B  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
|   B  |   A  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
|   C  |   D  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Something similar is achieved with a "covariance matrix." However the results would still have to be merged - respectively added up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this by swapping the columns if you need to:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Col1 < Col2 THEN Col1 ELSE Col2 END AS Col1,
        CASE WHEN Col1 < Col2 THEN Col2 ELSE Col1 END AS Col2
    FROM T
) t
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6fda/2)

Comment: You can make it more elegant using `LEAST`, `GREATEST` and getting rid of the outer query, like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c4f77/3). +1 for a nice query though.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - I prefer to write SQL that works across all platforms, where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Another try

```
SELECT LEAST(col1, col2) col11, GREATEST(col1, col2) col12 , COUNT(1) FROM X
GROUP BY col11, col12
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bd6a/26)

Comment: I like this answer the best. It's much shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE:** : Use [@Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154353/1395266)'s answer. Another try.

You can try the below code. [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0e7e1/4/0)

```
   SELECT COL1, COL2,  COUNT(*) AS COL3
   FROM (
    SELECT
    LEAST(COL1,COL2) AS COL1,
    GREATEST(COL1,COL2)  AS COL2
    FROM X
     ) AS Temp
    GROUP BY COL1,COL2;
```

Comment: CTE is SQL Server specific. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

Comment: @rurouni88 - it's not SQL Server specific. It's standard SQL (Oracle and Postgre also support it). It's just the MySQL doesn't follow the standard here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Fair enough. At any rate, it's not supported here. Let's not get me off on a rant. I spent the past week looking at different DB platforms different implementation of RAND() with SEED() :P

Comment: Your query seems wrong if OP has different data. See this [**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0e7e/3)

Comment: @RagingBull you are right, i misinterpreted the question

Comment: you need `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`, not MIN and MAX.

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 You may need to give different alias for your fields. Currently your query is not giving desired result. Check your fiddle itself

Comment: `GROUP BY COL1, COL2` prematurely creates duplicate rows (e.g. one for `a, b` and another for `b, a`).

Answer (score -1):

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bd6a/23

Use if statements and concat the 2 columns.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (CONCAT(C1,C2)) AS permutation, COUNT(1)
  FROM (SELECT
    IF(col1<=col2, col1, col2) as C1,
    IF(col2<col1, col1, col2) as C2
  FROM X) AS T
  GROUP BY permutation
;
```

Further explanation:
The if statements merely order the characters by ASCII value, so regardless of 'AB' or 'BA', it will always be represented as 'AB'

Comment: That may work with one character values, but if the real values were 'AA' and 'BB' this would falsely match 'AAB' and 'B'.