# How can I count the number of times I successfully compare data in two tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause, lookup, counting

I'm using the `where` method to lookup and compare two columns in two separate tables for identical values (order & player - both integers). I'm trying to count the number of times the lookup is successful (meaning successfully matches columns) for the current user, and then put that into an instance variable (<%= @total %>) to be displayed on the current user's index view (Once I have the count I'm multiplying by 5, but that's arbitrary). The real-world application for this could be a leaderboard-type-thing as users make different predictions and can be ranked based on how well those predictions match results.

Searched several answers that seemed to be in the neighborhood ([Counting occurrences of a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251328/counting-occurrences-of-a-given-input)) but not quite getting me toward a solution ([counting occurrences of items in an array python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866625/counting-occurrences-of-items-in-an-array-python)).
([How to count the number of times two values appear in two columns in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154204/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-two-values-appear-in-two-columns-in-any-order))

Predictions Controller:

```
  def index
    if current_user.present?
     @predictions = current_user.predictions.order(:order)
    else
     @predicitons = Prediction.all
    end
     @total = Result.where({ :order => @current_user.predictions.pluck(:order), :player_id => @current_user.predictions.pluck(:player_id) }).uniq.count*5.to_i
  end

  def new
    if current_user.predictions.count < '32'.to_i
     @prediction = Prediction.new(player_id: params[:player_id])
    else
  redirect_to "/predictions", alert: "You've maxed out on predictions"
    end
  end

  def create
   @prediction = current_user.predictions.build(predictions_params)
    if @prediction.save
     redirect_to "/predictions/new", notice: "This prediction's just been created."
    else
     redirect_to "/predictions", alert: "Something happened."
    end
  end

  def edit
  end
```

Results Controller:

```
 def new
  @result = Result.new
 end

 def create
  @result = Result.new(results_params)
   if @result.save
    redirect_to "/results"
   else
    render "New"
   end
 end
```

Tried different code in the predictions controller, index action. What I have here comes closest but I'm not getting consistent results as it **counts every prediction, right and wrong**. I've tried setting the variable to '0'.to_i before the lookup, but still getting inconsistent results.

```
@total = '0'.to_i
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something fairly obvious to more experienced eyes. I realize also there are more advanced ways to accomplish this that I'm not aware of.  A suggestion was made to store the variable in a session or cookie which is outside of my experience but I'm continuing to research this as an option.

Thanks for any feedback.

Example db entry match:

```
=> #<Prediction id: 126, round: nil, number: nil, created_at: "2017-03-21 05:44:32", updated_at: "2017-03-21 13:05:11", player_id: 2, order: 2, user_id: 2 >

=> #<Result id: 98, info: nil, created_at: "2017-04-20 15:37:17", updated_at: "2017-04-20 15:37:17", player_id: 2, order: 2>
```

Comment: Could you show example entries for both, your `predictions` and `results` tables and the expected "total" result based on these entires?

Comment: @Stefan, I've edited to show more actions. Does this help? Is this what you mean by entries? In terms of process, all users make predictions but only admin enters result. Within Predictions, users choose (1) order and (2) Player. Within Results, admin chooses (1) order and (2) Player. Player is a separate table. This is obvious. Just stating for clarity here.

Comment: With "entries" I mean the content of your database tables. Just some example rows, so we can understand what you are trying (or avoiding) to match.

Comment: Sure. Added what should be a match. Thanks.